# Trying to tell what enum character is at a specific location in a string

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum list of Parts:

```
public enum Parts
{
    Wall = (int)'#',
    Empty = (int)'-',
    Player = (int)'@',
    Goal = (int)'.',
    Block = (int)'$',
    BlockOnGoal = (int)'*',
    PlayerOnGoal = (int)'+'
};
```

And I have a string

```
string Level = "####\n#  #\n#@  #\n####";
```

so all of the items in the string are in the enum list
If i then call the function

```
public Parts WhatsAt(int row, int column)
    {
        return Parts.Wall;// Teachers comment but idk what he means "WRONG - but now no exception!  should look up Level or some better data structure"
    }
```

so when that function is called it will split the string on \n and then use the inputs into the function like a co-ordinates on a map to pinpoint a specific character in it.
Top left is row: 0, column: 0
bottom right is row: 4, column: 4

```
####
#  #
#@ #
####
```

How do I then make the function return what Part name is at a specified giving co-ordinate.

e.g.

```
Parts actual = WhatsAt(0, 2);
```

actual would then become Wall as that's what # means in the enum list
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Well, once you have a character (using split, [] and substring) you *could* cast your character to an int, and then cast that to your enum type, but that would be a hack (since you are assuming that the enum values are equal to the character values). A better data structure would be a `Dictionary<char,Part>` mapping characters to Parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you can try this:

```
public static Parts WhatsAt(int row, int column)
{
    var rows = Level.Split('\n');
    return (Parts)rows[row][column];
}
```

Comment: With schoolwork related questions, it is better to explain the answer, rather than just doing the schoolwork for the student. It is also preferable to write the simplest, most efficient code possible. I.e. not using LINQ's `ElementAt()` method when a simple indexer would suffice, and not making an intermediate cast to `int` when one can cast directly to the `enum` type in question.

Comment: yea i was thinking the propblem was something it wasnt the problem was simply just not returning it as an enum "(Parts)" type

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *anything*? If you can't get even far enough to make an attempt to write some code, you will be much better served by discussing with your teacher, as it means you've missed some critical concept that he was trying to convey.

In the meantime:

There are really two parts (at least) to your question:

1. How to find the `char` value for a given `row` and `column` value.
2. How to convert a `char` value to the `Parts` enum value. (*Aside: it is a .NET coding convention to make `enum` type names singular, not plural, unless the `enum` has the `[Flags]` attribute, and this convention is IMHO a useful one. So `Part` would be a better name for your `enum` type than `Parts`*).

On the first point, as you seem to already be aware, you can use the `string.Split()` method to obtain an array of `string` values from your original:

```
string[] rows = Level.Split('\n');
```

You can index this array with the `row` variable passed in to obtain the correct `string` value for that row. Within that `string` value, you can then user the `column` variable to index the desired `char` value for the location:

```
char location = rows[row][column];
```

On the second point, converting back to the `Parts` type is a simple cast:

```
Parts part = (Parts)location;
```

This does not change the actual value being used, but rather causes the `location` value to be reinterpreted as a `Parts` value, stored in the `part` variable.

And with that, you should have everything you need to write your `WhatsAt()` method. All of the above can even be expressed as a single expression if you like:

```
(Parts)Level.Split('\n')[row][column]
```

Comment: My question was "How do I then make the function return what Part name is at a specified giving co-ordinate.". which is simply that last line of code thanks

Comment: And I had done lots before just none of it was working so I chose to not include it in that example as it would have unnecessarily complicated it and most likely confused people who were trying to help.